# Spring - Validation of custom constraints

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I have a custom annotation @UniqueModel, which is validated by a ConstraintValidator:

```
@Component
public class UniquePlaceValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueModel, Model> {

    @Autowired
    private ModelRepository repository;

    public UniqueModelValidator() {
    }

    public void initialize(UniqueModel constraint) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Model model, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (repository == null)
            return true;

        Model dbModel = repository.findByNameAndMail(model.getName(), model.getMail());
        return dbModel == null;
    }
```

The problem is, that I need to do the validation **before** the safe()-method of the repository is called, otherwise the field injection won't work.

I therefor created a delegate-method with a @Valid-annotation, in order to force the unique-validation before:

```
Model save(@Valid Model model {
        return repository.save(model);
    }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, it seems like the @Valid-annotation is ignored by Spring.

How can I assure the correct timing of validation?

Comment: Can't you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820067/how-can-i-validate-constrains-on-entities-during-persist-of-an-entity-in-hiberna ?

Comment: Can you post your spring configuration as well? Having just the bean validation constraints is not enough. You might need to do additional configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Bean validation configuration you may need to annotate your repository bean with `@ValidateOnExecution`.
But I'm not sure if Spring does support this annoation (see [SPR-10641](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10641)) hence I'm using Spring's own `@Validated` annotation in my repository and service interfaces and method level validation works fine!
See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526620) and have a look into `MethodValidationPostProcessor` which clearly states *"Target classes with such annotated methods need to be annotated with Spring's `@Validated` annotation at the type level"*. So it seems to be pretty clear that you *have* to use `@Validated` instead of `@ValidateOnExecution` until SPR-10641 is fixed.